# Sort numbers in vimscript

Tags: sorting, vim

Experimenting with vimscript and reading the wonderful [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) (LVTHW), I realized that Vim wasn't sorting numbers the way I wanted it to.

For example this function from [LVTHW](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/39.html#immutable-data-structures)

```
function! Sorted(l)
    let new_list = deepcopy(a:l)
    call sort(new_list)
    return new_list
endfunction
```

surprised me when I called it with `Sorted([3, 1, 11, 2])`:

It returned `[1, 11, 2, 3]`.

I think Vim sorts those numbers in alphabetical order. But I'd expect the function to return the numbers in [natural order](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/):
`[1, 2, 3, 11]`

How can I convince Vim (7.4) to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to pass Vim's `sort` a comparator function, which in my case I called `NaturalOrder`.

```
" Sorts numbers in ascending order.
" Examples:
" [2, 3, 1, 11, 2] --> [1, 2, 2, 3, 11]
" ['2', '1', '10','-1'] --> [-1, 1, 2, 10]
function! Sorted(list)
  " Make sure the list consists of numbers (and not strings)
  " This also ensures that the original list is not modified
  let nrs= ToNrs(a:list)
  let sortedList = sort(nrs, "NaturalOrder")
  echo sortedList
  return sortedList
endfunction

" Comparator function for natural ordering of numbers
function! NaturalOrder(firstNr, secondNr)
  if a:firstNr < a:secondNr
    return -1
  elseif a:firstNr > a:secondNr
    return 1
  else 
    return 0
  endif
endfunction

" Coerces every element of a list to a number. Returns a new list without
" modifying the original list.
function! ToNrs(list)
  let nrs = []
  for elem in a:list
    let nr = 0 + elem
    call add(nrs, nr)
  endfor
  return nrs
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

if you've read the help doc of `sort()` function, you 'll see that you can give a `n` to `{func}` parameter to let sort do numerical sorting:

example:

```
:echo sort([3,1,11,2],'n')
[1, 2, 3, 11]
```

Comment: Hi Kent. Thanks for your answer. I did read the documentation and it makes no mention of the `n` trick. Also when I execute `:echo sort([3,1,11,2],'n')` I get the error `Unknown function: n`. Which version of Vim are you using?

Comment: @MatthiasBraun I am using `vim 7.4.473`: `When {func} is given and it is 'n' then all items will be
  sorted numerical `

Comment: I see. So `n` is a function like `NaturalOrder` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226987/sort-numbers-in-vimscript/27232550?noredirect=1#27226988), right?

Comment: @MatthiasBraun `(Implementation detail: This uses the
  strtod() function to parse numbers, Strings, Lists, Dicts and
  Funcrefs will be considered as being 0).`