# vim - How to query the pwd of a terminal buffer?

Tags: vim, terminal

Assuming I have a terminal buffer open that's cd'ed to `~/foo/bar` directory, how can I capture that directory to use in other vimscripts?

Comment: That doesn't get the current directory that the terminal buffer is in. It gets the current directory that Vim sets. It needs to be the directory that is **in** the terminal buffer.

Comment: Do you mean terminal buffer like in `:terminal`? Well, that would be hard. See https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-communication

Comment: That worked! Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

@phd's answer helped me find a solution

```
function s:get_closest_terminal()
    " Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232550/3626104
    let l:buffers = sort(tabpagebuflist('%'), 'n')

    for l:number in reverse(l:buffers)
        let l:type = getbufvar(l:number, '&buftype', '')

        if l:type == "terminal"
            return l:number
        endif
    endfor

    return -1
endfunction


function s:get_current_directory()
    let l:terminal_buffer = s:get_closest_terminal()

    if l:terminal_buffer == -1
        echoerr "No directory could be found"

        return ""
    endif

    " Example: "hostname@localhost: /home/username"
    let l:title = term_gettitle(l:terminal_buffer)

    " Example: "/home/username"
    return substitute(l:title, "^.*: ", "", "")
endfunction
```